# In the film of A Boy and His Dog "Blue Screamers" are mentioned -- do we know anything more about them?

Tags: harlan-ellison, a-boy-and-his-dog

Do we know anything more about "Blue Screamers"? For example, had they been human? What are their attributes?

BTW, maybe they were just called "screamers" -- maybe color was not mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're "burnpit screamers" in the book, and yes, in the movie, they were not actually shown, only heard, and at one point implied by a blue light.

Here's an excerpt from the book:

> “Well, I guess maybe I do. Maybe I have to remind you of some stuff. Like the time that burnpit-screamer came up out of the street and made a grab for you.”
>
> I shuddered. The motherfucker'd been green. Righteous stone green, glowing like fungus. My gut heaved, just thinking.
>
> “And I went for him, right?”
>
> I nodded. Right, mutt, right.
>
> “And I could have been burned bad, and died, and that would've been all of it for me, right or wrong, isn't that true?” I nodded again. I was getting pissed off proper. I didn't like being made to feel guilty. It was a fifty-fifty with Blood and me. He knew that. “But I did it, right?” I remembered the way the green thing had screamed. Christ, it was all ooze and eyelashes.

The scene plays very similarly in the film. I don't think it's ever completely spelled out in the text, but the burnpit screamers are implied to be survivors of radiation poisoning, deformed and glowing mutants who can deliver burns from residual radiation on contact.

Comment: I guess that's all we know. Always have been intrigued in fiction by characters that make a cameo appearance -- I remember the few lines spent on "revenants" in Interview with the Vampire (vampires that suffer brain damage due to starvation or something like that) but never found out any more about them either.